# Using JWT to send application user details to WSO2 API implementation

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am new to WSO2 API Manager. I wanted to Implement `JWT with WSO2 APIM`, so taking a reference from http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/12/customize-json-web-token-generation-with-wso2-api-manager-1.8.0/ and http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.in/2014/12/how-to-generate-custom-jwt-in-wso2-api.html.

When  I implement code from link, I see errors for the following. Please let me know which jar file we need? Could you please provide the complete steps in order to achieve this? No one has given all steps in details. Please help.

```
import org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConstants;
import org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dto.APIKeyValidationInfoDTO;
import org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.token.JWTGenerator;
import org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following maven dependencies

```
<groupId>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt</groupId>
<artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api</artifactId>
<version>1.2.3</version>

<groupId>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt</groupId>
<artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl</artifactId>
<version>1.2.3</version>
```

Comment: Could you please share link or comple maven dependency ?